# controler/routing in angular 1.5 and phonegap

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm trying to code a mobile application wich retrieve information from a distant json and loop on it to display a table.

The whole stuff doesn't work when i use build.phonegap.com but works when :

- I preview it on phonegap desktop (windows) in chrome
- I access to the server from phonegap application from my android
- I build the application for the emulator localy using node js and so on:

  ```
  phonegap run android --verbose
  ```

other angulars function seems working. For example to display wich tab of the menu is currently active i use:

```
<a href="#home" ng-click="menu='home'" ng-class="{active: menu=='home'}" class="nav-link icon-list-first"></a>
<a href="#page" ng-click="menu='page'" ng-class="{active: menu=='page'}" class="nav-link icon-list-second"></a>
```

So i guess angular is detected

I tryied to start angular by adding this on the top of index.html

```
<html ng-app="caviApp">
```

It's plenty functional (menu + routing) in the 3 platforms i quoted before (and only for menu in build.phonegap.com)

I also tried stuff like this only in

> \platforms\browser\www\index.html
>   to isolate android code

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var domElement = document.getElementById('html');
        angular.bootstrap(domElement, ["caviApp"]);

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

with an empty html opening tag

```
<html>
```

But in this solution, nothing work, nor neither menu nor neither the routing.

I'm using this code for routing :
var app = angular.module('caviApp', []);

```
app.controller('TableListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://www.myndd.com/myfile.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.mydatas = data;
    })
    $scope.orderProp='age';
});
```

If needed below my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <mete name="viewport"
          content="user-scalable=no, initiale-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
    <title>Hello world</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</head>
<body >
<nav class="nav">
    <a href="#home" ng-click="menu='home'" ng-class="{active: menu=='home'}" class="nav-link icon-list-first"></a>
    <a href="#page" ng-click="menu='page'" ng-class="{active: menu=='page'}" class="nav-link icon-list-second"></a>
</nav>
    <section class="view panel" ng-controller="TableListCtrl">
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="mydata in mydatas">
            <lignedata class="lignedatacss">
                <etique class="etiquettedata">
                    <img class="etiquette" src="{{mydata.img}}" />
                </etique>
                <descriptif class="descriptifdata">
                    <p class="title">{{mydata.name}}</p>
                    <p class="sub-title">{{mydata.ref}}</p>
                </descriptif>
            </lignedata>
        </li>
    </ul>
        <p>Total number of items: {{mydatas.length}}</p>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

So i guess my problem is a phonegap one and not an angular problem ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by compiling using my own computer and it works. also i don't know why but by creating an other project on phonegap cli it works also.